# Try to run a function only on Home

Tags: homepage, conditional-tags

I'm trying to run disable auto p filter on only my home page. In my functions.php file, I added this snippet:

```
function removeP(){
    if ( is_page( 4 ) ) {
        remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'removeP' );
```

It does not remove the filter on the homepage.

Comment: by `homepage` I'm assuming you mean Home Page of a website, not a blog. So you can modify the answers below by changing `is_home()` to `is_front_page()` - which will look for the template `front-page.php` and modify it accordingly.

Comment: never hardcode post IDs, if you must, use post slugs instead.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling it on the wrong hook, and you're calling the wrong [conditional function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to test.

When the `after_setup_theme` hook is fired, WordPress hasn't finished processing wether you're on a page or a homepage yet.

You should also ***never*** pass in hardcoded post IDs. In this case [`is_home`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) works, as might `is_front_page`. If you really must reference a hardcoded posts, and I beg that you don't, use a post slug instead, or even better, store a post ID in an option and present a drop down menu to let the user choose in the backend.

Your function should be something like this:

```
function removeP(){
    if ( is_home () ) {
        remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'removeP' );
```

Comment: Wouldn't using a post slug be worse than using a static post ID? The user can change the post slug, but to change the post ID they would have to delete the page entirely.

Comment: No, a post ID could change because of an import export,  or any other number of reasons. I would suggest that neither are used. In a post slug situation at least the slug can be edited back. I would personally opt instead to have a post ID stored in an option with a GUI

Comment: @TomJNowell you are right. Didn't think about the hook. Bad me

Answer (score 1):

change `if ( is_page( 4 ))` to `if (is_home() )` so:

```
function removeP(){
    if ( is_home() ) {
        remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'removeP' );
```

Comment: Not working. Actually, home page get content from other pages. But I already try to inform te id of this pages.

Comment: You're going to have to give us a little bit more info then on what you're trying to do. the `is_home()` conditional is how you run functions only on the home template.

Comment: Russel Found a solution: I add remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); on the top of home page template.

Comment: ```after_setup_theme``` is too early to run ```is_home()```.